# Cannot infer value type even when explict

Tags: rust

I need to split a string on whitespace and several other chars.

```
let mut text = String::from("foo,bar baz");
for word in text.split(|c| c.is_whitespace::<char>() || c == ',' ).filter(|&s| !s.is_empty()) {
    println!("{}", word);
}
```

However the compiler says:

```
error: the type of this value must be known in this context
 --> src/main.rs:4:32
  |
4 |     for word in text.split(|c| c.is_whitespace::<char>() || c == ',').filter(|&s| !s.is_empty()) {
  |                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

What am I doing wrong? Why can it not infer the type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`.split`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.split) method accepts anything satisfying the `Pattern<'a>` trait bound. In this case, Rust cannot know what type of function this is because it does not know what the type of the function parameter is.

Looking at [`Pattern`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/pattern/trait.Pattern.html) there is an implementation for `FnMut`:

```
impl<'a, F> Pattern<'a> for F 
where
    F: FnMut(char) -> bool,
```

To tell the compiler that this is the pattern you want, you need to give enough information for it to know that your closure matches this.

In this case, this means you can add `: char`. You must also remove `::<char>`, because it is an `unneeded type parameter`. e.g.

```
text.split(|c| c.is_whitespace::<char>() || c == ',' )
```

to

```
text.split(|c: char| c.is_whitespace() || c == ',' )
```

Comment: Or `|c| char::is_whitespace(c) || c == ','` — for whatever reason I dislike specifying types in closure argument lists.

Comment: Fair. Are there any community guidelines for stuff like this?

Comment: I don't think there is anything for this particular case; this is just my pure preference. Rustfmt is my normal go-to for the official style.